# Backlight Bleeding , Flash lighting on Brand New Asus Laptop

Tags: display, backlight

I bought an ASUS VivoBook E12 E203NAH-FD057T (Intel Celeron Dual Core N3350 / 4GB / 500GB / 11.6" HD LED just three days back.

I noticed that it has a severe back light bleeding / flashlighting issue which is quite bad on the top left corner of the screen.  I am trying to get it returned as I find it completely unacceptable , this kind of defect in a brand new laptop. However , the return process is so tedious, and they make it especially hard. The amount of hours I will have to spend to get this returned will be a lot ( not to mention the sheer frustration involved in doing so ).

I read somewhere that backlight bleed is a common issue with LED screens and that it should not effect the quality of the screen in the long-run. Is this true? Or should I put in the effort to return the laptop?

Comment: It would probably help if you mentioned which country you are in and who the retailer was. And this isn't really a computer-related question, it is a question about returning unsatifactory goods, so you should be able to find a better site to ask on.

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the screen in terms of physical quality would not be impacted by this, however if you describe quality in terms of how enjoyable your screen looks, then yes this impacts it.

You should return this